# Merge two pages in pdf to single pdf one page

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I have the following code that merges a pdf file with two pages to a single pdf with one page only
Page two goes below page one in portrait form and everything till now is OK.
Is it possible to add padding white spaces around each page before merging ?

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
from PyPDF2.pdf import PageObject

def merge_two_pages_into_single(pdffile, outfile):
    reader = PdfFileReader(open(pdffile, 'rb'))
    page_1 = reader.getPage(0)
    page_2 = reader.getPage(1)

    translated_page = PageObject.createBlankPage(None, page_1.mediaBox.getWidth(), page_1.mediaBox.getHeight()*2)
    translated_page.mergeScaledTranslatedPage(page_1, 1, 0, page_1.mediaBox.getHeight())
    translated_page.mergePage(page_2)

    writer = PdfFileWriter()
    writer.addPage(translated_page)

    with open(outfile, 'wb') as f:
        writer.write(f)

merge_two_pages_into_single('231072600062.pdf', 'MergedPDF.pdf')
```

Comment: Is it possible to add any space between the two merged pages?